# Creating a layout where a view is anchored to bottom (but also stacked on top) of ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to start by showing what I'm trying to achieve, and I'll move on to what I I know and have tried.

[image: Image here]

• What I've tried:

1. I've tried **Collapsing Toolbar Layout**, which doesn't give the effect that's in the image, where the bottom view with Title and description is stacked on Top of ImageView.
2. I used `BottomSheet`, but unfortunately I don't see any way to anchor the `BottomSheet` to the bottom of `ImageView`, I tried to do it using `app:layout_anchor="@id/imageView"`, but it still covers the complete image, and without that, it does as intended, but it doesn't stay **below** the `ImageView`, if the image is long, it'll cover a lot of part of that image.
3. I tried the following layout, (where `@drawable/background_blog_description` is the drawable with rounded corners at top). Also, in the layout below, I haven't added `layout_anchor` tag because it covers entire Image (Even if I specify the `anchor_gravity="bottom"`).

   ```
   <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/iv_notice_image_complete"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="top"
       android:transitionName="iv_notice_image" />

   <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
       android:id="@+id/acm_nsv"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:behavior_hideable="false"
       app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="@drawable/background_blog_description"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:paddingStart="20dp"
               android:paddingTop="20dp"
               android:paddingEnd="20dp"
               android:paddingBottom="100dp"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/tv_notice_title_complete"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
                   android:padding="5dp"
                   android:text="This will be the title of notice"
                   android:textColor="@color/black"
                   android:textSize="30sp"
                   android:textStyle="bold"
                   android:transitionName="tv_notice_title" />


               <WebView
                   android:id="@+id/mdv_notice_description_complete"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                   android:transitionName="tv_notice_description" />

           </LinearLayout>

       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

   </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


   <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/fab_notice_back"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_gravity="top|start"
       android:layout_margin="8dp"
       app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
       app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back" />

   </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
   ```

At this point I'm kinda blank as to what I should do to make something like below. It must be something really simple, but I'm not seeing it for some reason. My only requirement is that the bottom Layout/View of the `ImageView` should be on top of it, with a small part of Image (20dp maybe?) under that view, and when scrolled, it should cover the image.

So, `BottomSheet` which can be anchored at the bottom of `ImageView`, but with some part of Image going under the BottomSheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your image within an `AppBarLayout` and then add `app:behavior_overlapTop=20dp` to your `NestedScrollView`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior.html#setOverlayTop(int)

Comment: Well.. that was simple, I just didn't see it. I just don't understand why they don't show all the available tags for a layout. For example, it didn't suggest me this behavior_overlapTop and many other tags in XML editor.